# Unable to import keras-tuner: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' has no attribute 'RandomRotation'

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, importerror, keras-tuner

I followed the following steps:

1. Installed Ananconda
2. Created a conda environment for my project in PyCharm with Python 3.6
3. Installed packages in PyCharm
4. Used `conda install -n env_name -c conda-forge keras-tuner` in Anaconda prompt to install keras tuner.

Initially there was a problem with the packages which were taking forever to install. The problem seems to have appeared suddenly. I did a full uninstallation of Anaconda using the online uninstallation guide https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ and reinstalled it using `Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64`

Comment: which tensorflow version are you using?